# How to effectively show an icon in GWT only in the row the user hit with the mouse?

Tags: gwt

I like this effect (which is used here in StackOverflow too to remove comments) that when the mouse enters a row an icon is shown to remove this row. If the mouse doesn't hit any row there is no icon at all.

I solved this in my GWT application but I am not so happy with the solution because it seems hat it consumes a lot of CPU. What I did: Every row has an icon with is `setVisible(false)` at the beginning. To the table I add a `MouseMoveHandler` and if the mouse hits a row this image gets visible. Another `MouseOutHandler` is added to the table which hides every image if the mouse leaves the table.

Do you see an alternative to solve this problem effectively?

Answer (score 1):

Since the user will never have their mouse in more than one row at a time -- have you tried instantiating just one icon and then attaching/removing it from each row on your `MouseMoveHandler`/ `MouseOutHandler`? The result will likely be different. Also, what are you using to monitor the CPU use?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using only one icon, a common mistake is creating more than 1 handler. Using **a lot** of handlers to do the same thing gets your browser bogged down with objects.

Instead of

```
for (final MyRowWidget row : rows) {
    row.addMouseMoveHandler(new MouseMoveHandler() { // a new one every time is bad
        public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEvent event) {
            row.doShowImage();
        }
    });
}
```

Do

```
private static final MouseMoveHandler THE_ONE_AND_ONLY = new MouseMoveHandler() {
    public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEvent event) {
        MyRowWidget rowWidget = (MyRowWidget) event.getSource();
        rowWidget.doShowImage();
    }
});

...

for (HasAllMouseHandlers row : rows) {
    row.addMouseMoveHandler(THE_ONE_AND_ONLY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a panel with image in it and move the panel to corresponding location in row that cursor is in right now using `MouseMoveHandler/ MouseOutHandler`?